# How to create an additional table to link the models?

Tags: django, django-models

There are two models `Modules()` and `ParentCategory()`. They are not linked in any way in the database.

```
class Modules(models.Model):
    .....

class ParentCategory(models.Model):
    ....
```

I want to make the connection between them on the following principle. One module contains several categories. Described this structure with a dictionary where dictionary key - module name and the value of the list of categories belonging to this module.

```
pc_to_modules_assign = {
                            "DTH": ['COMMON S2P', 'COMMON SOURCING', 'SERVICES', 'SOURCING'],
                            "KLK": ['COMMON S2P', 'COMMON SOURCING', 'SERVICES', 'SXM'],
                            "ODJU": ['COMMON S2P', 'SERVICES', 'Analytics'],
                            "TD": ['COMMON S2P', 'SERVICES', 'CLM'],
                            "MNH": ['COMMON S2P', 'SERVICES', 'eProcurement'],
                            "OPI": ['COMMON S2P', 'SERVICES', 'I2P'],
                            "AP": ['COMMON S2P', 'SERVICES', 'I2P', 'AP'],
                            "DF": ['COMMON S2P', 'COMMON SOURCING', 'SERVICES', 'SOURCING', 'SXM', 'Analytics', 'CLM'],
                            "CVB": ['COMMON S2P', 'SERVICES', 'eProcurement', 'I2P'],
                            "GFT": ['COMMON S2P', 'COMMON SOURCING', 'SERVICES', 'SOURCING', 'SXM', 'Analytics', 'CLM', 'eProcurement', 'I2P']
                             }
```

There is one `primary` category in the list. What kind of connections should be used in such a model or what fields are needed approximately. Something like that.

```
class PCtoModules(models.Model):
    m = .....Modules
    pc = ....ParentCategory
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

But I'm confused as to what type of connection to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you don't need extra table for that. I would connect them in the following way:

```py
class Modules(models.Model):
    primary_category = models.ForeignKey('ParentCategory')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('ParentCategory')

class ParentCategory(models.Model):
    ....
```

Now if we say that `module` is an instance of your `Module` class, you can access
the primary category of  the module:

```
module.primary_category
```

and all the assigned categories with:

```
module.categories
```